# Multiprocessing/threading on a function

Tags: python, multithreading

Right now my function is using 25% of my cpu, and I have 4 cores, so I'm guessing it's maxing out 1 core?

Anyway.. I need a way to run my function on 4 threads/processes to utilize all of my CPU, I have looked on stackoverflow how to do this already but they are all for functions that require arguments..mine doesn't, nor do I understand it very well.

My function is pretty much this

```
def loop():
    for i in range(0,831838):
        ...
```

Comment: How are you already taking up 25%? Are you running multiple threads?

Comment: No, I'm doing aes decryption in my for loop.

Comment: Maybe you could create a `multiprocessing` subclass and put this function in there and then create 4 different threads. But is that what the other posts said?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out..

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
jobs = []
for i in range(4):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=loop)
    jobs.append(p)
    p.start()
```